# Рабочее пространство в кастомном файле

Tags: android, android-sdk

#### Задача:

Необходимо в Activity сделать рабочее пространство. Имеется ввиду прямоугольное поле в которое можно вставлять изображения, текст, аудио и т.п. Все эти компоненты можно масштабировать и размещать в любом месте рабочей области. Саму же область можно масштабировать и сохранять в файл. Аналог Adobe Illustrator

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Adobe Illustrator - это(как бы так сказать) не самая простая задача. И как бы глупо это не звучало, но...если Вы не представляете как Вам решать подобную задачу, то браться за неё Вам еще рано. И данная задача слишком большая и комплексная для обсуждения в одном вопросе. Я бы посоветовал Вам начать с чего-нибудь попроще...например с холста как в Microsoft Paint'е и одного инструмента - карандаша...с одним цветом, параллельно изучить паттерны проектирования..а там дальше виднее будет, если Вы останетесь верны своему желанию...но путь Вас ждёт неблизкий

Comment: для вдохновения можете попробовать открыть и почитать исходники какого-нибудь графического редактора...например GIMP: https://github.com/GNOME/gimp . Приятного чтения.

Comment: @МихаилРебров
Спасибо за помощь. Я прислушаюсь к вашему совету.